# tips on using checkbox inputs in editable javascript form

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, input, checkbox

**Situation:**

I'm using javascript to put together a user profile form and am in need of a little help with regard to checkbox inputs.  The goal is to have a form that returns all input information to a mysql database (such as name, job, etc etc), then for the form to also be updated by the user, once saved.

I've been able to get the database query to work with the text inputs so that users can see data they've previously saved.  I do however have one spot where I need a checkbox input for each user for a simple binary answer. I figured I'd store the information such that checked=1 unchecked=0.

**Problem:**

While I can get the checked info to save just fine as value=1, I'm looking for a way to make the box check display the check once the person has saved the answer and has come back to edit it.  Also, I'm looking for a way to also allow that user to uncheck the box and overwrite value=1 with value=0.

I figure I could use some sort of sloppy if-statement fiasco to accomplish this, but I was just wondering what best practices are generally used in this situation.  (If you can't tell I'm slowly learning my way through web development)

My checkbox is displayed like so:

```
<tr><td id='ownershipquestion' colspan='2'>Does this person have an ownership stake?</td><td id='ownershipbox'><input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner' value='1'/>Yes</td></tr>\
```

Previously saved values are obtained like so:

```
owner: $("#dialog input[name=owner]").attr("value"),
```

And updated value is returned like so:

```
item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can read the checked status (i.e. is it checked or not) via the `prop()` method (read [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)).

This gives you a `bool` value. As an input of the type `checkbox` has also a (text) value, you'd probably do something like this:

```
owner: $('input[name=foobar]').prop("checked")
    ? $('input[name=foobar]').val()
    : '',
```

Later on, you can set it (from integer), like so:

`item.find("input[name=owner]").prop("checked", p.owner ? true: false);`

Mind that your HTML code above shows a `text` input field..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm quite new to javascript and so I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how I neeed to apply the answer.  With the first line of code, this would be necessary for retrieving it from the database, correct?  A couple questions: What is the significance of the question mark, multiple lines and empty quotes?  In the second code entry, I assume that would be the way we would write it into the array.  Questions: what is the significance of the question mark and where would the integer values go (or is there a better way to save it?)  Thanks again for the response!

Comment: Also RE: HTML CODE shwos a text input field:  Thanks for catching that, I'd copied the wrong line in.  It's fixed now.

Comment: For better explaining how to apply the answer, a full code example from you would help.
The question mark is part of the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript). In short: `a = b ? 1 : 0;` is short for `if (b) { a = 1; } else { a = 0; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Here's the context in which it's being used: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/People_java.txt